# OpenCV Java Creating Mat With BufferedImage Data Returns Error

Tags: java, opencv

I am very new to OpenCV, have just set it up, and want it working perfectly.  I tried to use a basic grayscale image OpenCV source code that I found online to test it out.  The code returns an error.  Here is the code and the error it returns:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
public class BlackAndWhite {
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
   try {
      System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
      File input = new File("Picture.jpg");
      BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);    

      byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().
      getDataBuffer()).getData();
      Mat mat = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
      mat.put(0, 0, data);

      Mat mat1 = new Mat(image.getHeight(),image.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC1);
      Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat1, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

      byte[] data1 = new byte[mat1.rows()*mat1.cols()*(int)(mat1.elemSize())];
      mat1.get(0, 0, data1);
      BufferedImage image1=new BufferedImage(mat1.cols(),mat1.rows()
      ,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
      image1.getRaster().setDataElements(0,0,mat1.cols(),mat1.rows(),data1);

      File ouptut = new File("grayscale.jpg");
      ImageIO.write(image1, "jpg", ouptut);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
   }
}
```

> Error: Provided data element number (200984) should be multiple of the
>   Mat channels count (3)

Comment: In which line does it crash ? Don't forget that image has multi-channel component. In a byte array, with a BGR image, you will have one cell for each color (3). So when you create a byte[], you have to take width, height and channel number. (Ex: w * h * 3)

Comment: I have been experimenting and have found that the error is caused by the number of bytes in the byte[] not being divisible by 3.  I believe this is because the program needs a left, middle, and right byte.  If you use a .jpg and not a .png the program will work.

Comment: It's because JPEG has 3 component (red, green and blue). For PNG, it has 4 (red, green, blue and Alpha for transparency).